# Is there a way to disable automatic flush of output buffer

Tags: php, output-buffering

Is there a way to disable automatic output buffer flush in PHP? I can always use **ob_clean** (or one of derivative functions) but that still leaves us with situations where code execution is interrupted. Proper error handler containing buffer clean will again deal with most of those. But what if for example script encounters the die / exit command during the execution? It will terminate the script and buffer content will still get auto flushed to client. The only way to be 100% sure seems to be disabling auto-flush completly. But I'm not sure how to achieve that (if possible at all).

Comment: Have you verified that the buffer isn't flushed simply, because it is full? If this is the case, then the only way is to increase buffer size (no idea how).

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't have die or exit in your code, especially in places where output is pending. On most cases, a script should have a bootstrap.php file, which is run from beginning to end. It starts when the script starts, and when it ends, so does the script.

Comment: I am aware of that. But I'm asking this question in purpose of sanitizing an old and large project. There is a lot of code written there, by several people and some parts as old as from 1999 (and obviously a lot of very poor code, I already had to deal with SQL injection holes). Best thing I can do is grab each output into buffer and process it. It seems to be working fine but God knows if there isnt something there that will still terminate the script in way which I did not anticipated. No auto-flush would at least make me certain in this aspect.

Answer (score -3):

Another solution, you can always implement your *OWN* buffer, and flush when you feel so ...
So your code should begin as:

```
$buffer='';
```

After this, when you plan to print() something, simply replace print() with $buffer.=

Once you decide to flush the buffer, you simply do:

```
print($buffer); $buffer='';
```

By doing so, you not only can 100% control your buffer, but also you might set additional headers during the execution of your script, which can come really handy in some cases ...

Comment: Could anyone who's doing a downvote on my answer please make the courtesy to tell the REASON WHY ?!
This is an excellently working solution for the problem!